# Creating a where query in rails from an array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I need to make a where query from an array where each member of the array is a 'like' operation that is ANDed. Example:

```
SELECT ... WHERE property like '%something%' AND property like '%somethingelse%' AND ...
```

It's easy enough to do using the ActiveRecord `where` function but I'm unsure how to sanitize it first. I obviously can't just create a string and stuff it in the `where` function, but there doesn't seem to be a way possible using the `?`.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest way to build your LIKE patterns is string interpolation:

```
where('property like ?', "%#{str}%")
```

and if you have all your strings in an array then you can use ActiveRecord's query chaining and [`inject`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject) to build your final query:

```
a = %w[your strings go here]
q = a.inject(YourModel) { |q, str| q.where('property like ?', "%#{str}%") }
```

Then you can `q.all` or `q.limit(11)` or whatever you need to do to get your final result.

---

Here's a quick tutorial on how this works; you should review the [Active Record Query Interface Guide](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html) and the [`Enumerable` documentation](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html) as well.

If you had two things (`a` and `b`) to match, you could do this:

```
q = Model.where('p like ?', "%#{a}%").where('p like ?', "%#{b}%")
```

The `where` method returns an object that supports all the usual query methods so you can chain calls as `M.where(...).where(...)...` as needed; the other query methods (such as `order`, `limit`, ...) return the same sort of object so you can chain those as well:

```
M.where(...).limit(11).where(...).order(...)
```

You have an array of things to LIKE against and you want to apply `where` to the model class, then apply `where` to what that returns, then again until you've used up your array. Thing that look like a feedback loop tend to call for [`inject`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject) (AKA `reduce` from "map-reduce" fame):

> **inject(initial) {| memo, obj | block } → obj**
>
> Combines all elements of *enum* by applying a binary operation, specified by a block or a symbol that names a method or operator.
>
> If you specify a block, then for each element in *enum* the block is passed an accumulator value (*memo*) and the element [...] the result becomes the new value for *memo*. At the end of the iteration, the final value of *memo* is the return value for the method.

So `inject` takes the block's output (which is the return value of `where` in our case) and feeds that as an input to the next execution of the block. If you have an array and you `inject` on it:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
r = a.inject(init) { |memo, n| memo.m(n) }
```

then that's the same as this:

```
r = init.m(1).m(2).m(3)
```

Or, in pseudocode:

```
r = init
for n in a
    r = r.m(n)
```

Comment: Woah! That works! I'm new to rails (and ruby), do you mind giving me a short explanation of what's going on here exactly?

Comment: @Mattieu: Does that help? It can be difficult to explain functional things that you use all the time, there's usually an "aha!" moment where you get it and it is all magic before that.

Comment: @Mattieu, If you don't afraid to add gems, take a look at squeel https://github.com/ernie/squeel. It has awesome feature `like_all`/`like_any`: `queries = %w[ruby rails].map{|s|"%#{s}%"}; Product.where{title.like_all queries}`.

Comment: @muistooshort Wow thank you so much, that's a great explanation! I hadn't realized that the `where` methods (and all those others) could be chained! Makes perfect sense to use with the `inject` to create the query, very clever! I really appreciate the help!

Comment: @jdoe The codebase isn't mine, but I'll look into it, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you're using AR, do something like `Model.where(property: your_array)` , or `Model.where("property in (?)", your_array)` This way, everything is sanitized

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but won't that do an "="? I need to do a "like"

Comment: you're correct, I think I skipped the like part when I read the question

Answer (score 0):

Let's say your array is model_array, try Array select:

```
model_array.select{|a|a.property=~/something/ and a.property=~/somethingelse/}
```

Of course you can use any regex as you like.